# best way to "bring up my post" in php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a custom-built CMS with php & mysql, and I was wondering which is the best way to put an old article (for example) posted in 2013 back to top (so I don't have to re-post it). It's like a "bump" (bring up my post) which is used in forums.

I was thiking to add a new *date_order* column to the **Articles** tables in mysql, and then "order by" that field, so the original posting date won't change, and anytime I want to bring up a post, I just "bump" it (change that fields date to the current timestamp). But this will increase the database size of course.

Any beter idea?

Comment: Sounds like an idea. Storage space is not an issue any more. So go!

Comment: I think your idea is a quite good one. Why should database size matter?

Comment: As you said, just have two columns, posted_date and bump_date and order by the bump date first and posted_date second. Then if the two dates are the same, it'll just show as normal with bumped posts first.

Comment: You _could_ also physically move the article to the top (reorganize the table) and use natural ordering. But that would be a _horrible_ design..

Comment: Set it as a "pinned" post using a boolean pin column. Then orderby a combination of columns, like post date, author, title, category, etc. You just change the SQL query to whatever you want.

Comment: @MarioA and Arkasha , I don't care about the size itself. I was only worried that adding a new column, and that column being a duplicate for 95% of other articles (i.e. those not 'bumped') may impact the performance. I was thinking also to create a new table named **bumped** and put the _id_ and _bumpedDate_ only for those articles which I have bumped. I would thus save some space but then I probably would have to join or combine two tables, or something like that.

Which would be the optimal choice according to you guys? (thanks in advance)

Answer (score 3):

Add a tinyint column called "pinned" with a default value of 0.  Make the value of the pinned field 1 for any post you want pinned to the top.

In your SQL string `ORDER BY pinned DESC, DATE` (or whatever).

Using this method, you could have a button that only you can see (because you are logged in), clicking it would set `pinned = 1` for that post.

Comment: He could do this or use an enum but it would remain at the top forever? Maybe not what he's after?

Comment: And if it is no longer wanted to be at the top, set pinned = 0

Comment: I think the general design of the forum bump is to put it back to the top at the time it is bumped and then it will disappear down the forum as date progresses.

Comment: Ahhh...you are right.  I will leave the answer as it is still useful, though not quite what the OP was after.

Comment: It's the way to go if he wants to manually pin to the top, it's more of the sticky form that way though!

Comment: It is as @sark9012 said. I want it to go down the paging as new articles are posted.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the table structure you could favor some ids in your ordering, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY FIELD(id, 11, 51), date ASC
```

This would first display the articles with id 11 and 51, then the rest ordered by date.